# java convert xmldate to string date, probably timezone issue

Tags: java, xml, date, datetime, converters

I have dates in XML

```
 <date>1980-03-07+03:00</date>
```

I use this data in my tests and i get it from XML, but in the web page it is displayed in `dd.MM.yyyy` form, so i have to convert it to that format. I have following method for this:

```
public String convertXMLDateToString(String xmlDate) throws ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException {
        return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date(DatatypeConverter.parseDate(xmlDate).getTimeInMillis())) ;
    }
```

but this is returning `06.03.1980` . It is probably a timezone issue - how to i get the right date? The reason for using strings is that these are webdriver tests that i am writing.

Comment: I don't quite understand the question.  Are you saying you want to ignore the timezone, and just deal with the day, month and year?  If that's what you want, then maybe you should split on the "+" character - that is, you'll parse then format `xmlDate.split("\\+")[0]`.  If you can confirm that that is what you are asking, I will turn this comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its returning actually the correct date. Either your test data is corrupted or you have a bug in your application. However if you're sure, that there's no bug and test data isn't corrupted, you can set the correct time zone manually, by doing something like this:

```
Calendar calendar = DatatypeConverter.parseDate(xmlDate);
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());

return new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").format(new Date(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
```